# Knitr not printing ggplots when chunk is called programmatically in a for loop

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am not sure what is wrong in my attempt to re-use a chunk (dynamically created)  in a for-loop. When i render the .RMD file using rmarkdown:render. The ggplots are not getting embedded and am getting the following messages.

```
<img src="/myhome_dir/hostsum_new_files/figure-html/sub_chunk_8998-1.png" width="1920" />
```

However if call the same chunk outside the for-loop, the ggplots are embedded very nicely.

User can provide a list of names that they want to graphs of, if  not provided than i run through a predefined lists.

So basically a

```
if (len(user_list)) >= 1){
     # print the graphs for the elements in user_list
} else {
    # we go through a set of predefined lists
    for (pre-def-list in pre-def-lists){
       # print the graphs for the elements in pre-def-list
       # go through each list
     } 
}
```

Since the code for printing is the same, so wanted to optimize by reusing chunks..

```
---
title: "Investigation"
output: html_notebook
---
```

#### This is my reusable part of the code

````
```{r mstr_vlun_chart,eval=FALSE,results='asis'}
for (host in host_list){
    f = ggplot()
    print(f)
}
```
````

#### this works well and embeds the plots in the final html file, if i call it in this manner

````
```{r}
host_list = c("comp2","comp3")  
```

```{r vlun_ioprof_data,ref.label='mstr_vlun_chart',results='asis',eval=TRUE}
```
````

#### However when i attempt at re-use of chunks, the ggplots are not embedded, the chunk is called and all gets executed..

````
```{r}

host_list = c()
if (length(host_list)==0){

   for (int_grp in ls(pattern='^hstgrp')) {
     # just an example.. on what the final outcome wil be.
     host_list <- c("comp2","comp3")
     loop_chunk <- paste0("
          `","```{r vlun_ioprof", floor(runif(1) * 10000), 
           ",ref.label='mstr_vlun_chart',results='asis',eval=TRUE}",
            "\n`","```
        ")
 cat(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = loop_chunk), quiet = 
 FALSE))
  }
} 
```
````

This is what is being printed in the html file when i use the "For loop" method.

```
<!-- rnb-text-begin -->
<!-- rnb-text-end -->
<!-- rnb-chunk-begin -->
<!-- rnb-plot-begin -->

<img src="/myhome_dir/hostsum_new_files/figure-html/sub_chunk_8998-1.png" width="1920" 
/>
<!-- rnb-plot-end -->
<!-- rnb-chunk-end -->
<!-- rnb-text-begin -->
<!-- rnb-text-end -->
```

Comment: You should write an R function for the plots, not try to reuse chunks this way.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, moved to this model :) and its working well. Just curious to know why my attempt(though not recommended) didnt work..

Comment: I suspect knitr just does one pass through the file.  Added chunk code won't be seen.